# How can I set language of ViewController instead of device's language?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to set language of my ViewController( all strings have to load in my language), but device's language could be different. 
And could be different text direction LTR or RTL.
How can I do it?

Example: 
Device's language: Russian

View Controller: English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my approach to this case would be the following

```
class Strings {

    static var sharedInstance: Strings = Strings()

    // MARK: Properties
    var name: String

    init(){
        switch /* your custom language */ {
        case /* english */:
            self.name = "name"
        }
        // you can add multiple choices here
        default:
            self.name = "russian name"
    }

}
```

- and in the VC

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    // MARK: Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // add it here if the app don't have the option to change the language while running
        // Strings.sharedInstance = Strings()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        // or add it here if the app does have the option to change the language while running
        Strings.sharedInstance = Strings()
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it work with strings on storyboard? Common strings I translate with LocalizedString() class

Comment: this way is alternative for the storyboard strings file as the .strings file read the language from the system